# Creating Directories With Variable Names

Tags: python-3.x, variables, directory

I'm trying to write a script to automatically create media storage directories with names generated from given directory names following a transcode.

We get in directories with this format:

```
DAY3_012422
```

and I would like to create directories with the following format:

```
Showname_DAY3_012422
```

All I have is a standard mkdir:

```
import os

path = "/Users/mediamanager/Desktop/Showname_DAYx_y"

os.mkdir(path, 0o755)
```

Is there any way I could add a variable within my path object to fill that info, assuming x = 3 and y = 012422?

Comment: There are multiple ways to create strings based on other variables in Python, have you tried anything? Done any research?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just define complete path with variable as

```
x, y = "3", "012422"
path = "/Users/mediamanager/Desktop/Showname_DAY" + x + "_" + y
os.mkdir(path)
```

It'll not work when dir already exists.